# SVG text filled with linearGradient is blurred on iPhone with retina display (Safari, Chrome)

Tags: iphone, svg, retina-display, linear-gradients

I'm using SVG to render a text with gradient fill on HTML page. There is a problem on iPhone device with retina display: a text with gradient is blurred initially and isn't redrawn when page is zoomed. A text with solid fill is scaled properly and looks sharp. Here is a link to screenshot of a test HTML page, rendered in Chrome (25.0.1364.86) on iOS (6.1.2):

https://khttqq.dm1.livefilestore.com/y1pKFYPUS7WWQbPeMRk8akuOuxfWa7i8pTtzvJA40WgC78RLnlybUKDBbt5KVaWnORUgHISDawbCZb85UXMmF2KeDVqLsdbaVVx

Here is a code:

```
<svg style="width: 0; height: 0;">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
          <stop offset="0" style="stop-color: rgb(255,255,255); stop-opacity: 1;"/>
          <stop offset="100" style="stop-color: rgb(60,60,60); stop-opacity: 1;"/>
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
</svg>

<svg style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 300px; height: 150px;">
    <text x="0" y="110" font-family="Arial" font-size="110" fill="url(#gradient)">
        TEST
    </text>
</svg>

<svg style="position: absolute; top: 100; left: 0; width: 300px; height: 150px;">
    <text x="0" y="110" font-family="Arial" font-size="110" fill="red">
        TEST
    </text>
</svg>
```

I'm looking for a way to get a sharp text with gradient fill on mentioned platform.
Really appreciate any replies that would help to clarify this issue.

Comment: Have you reported this bug to Apple?